# How to build .lib files using Code::Blocks IDE

Tags: c, static-libraries, codeblocks, .a, .lib

I have a C project which I would like to *build* as a *static library* and not as a executable.

My high level environment is:

- IDE: Code::Blocks 16.01
- Operating System: Windows 7
- Compiler: MinGW    (GCC port for Windows)

As a build target option, I select static library (instead of executable) and select build.

Seems to work fine. Problem is, the output is a .a file (which I understand is the Unix/Linux format) and not the windows format of .lib.

Any hints on where I can look to solve this?

Comment: Do you specifically need .lib? Or do you just want to build a static library? If latter, then everything is okay. MinGW uses .a for static libs even on Windows.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I didnt know that. If that is the case, a .a would suffice. As a matter of interest, if I specifically wanted to use .lib what would be the course of action?

Comment: I don't know, but I assume there is a way, because MinGW seemingly can link against .lib's.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem, seems there is a solution:

In the main menu, open `Project->Properties...` and there the `Build targets` tab. Select your target, for example `Release`.

In the text field `Output filename`, change `bin\Release\yourLib.a` to `bin\Release\yourLib.lib` and untick the checkbox `Auto-generate filename extension`.

Now, building your project generates a `.lib` file instead of a `.a` file.

Don't forget to do the same steps for the `Debug` target, if you want to generate Debug `.lib` instead of `.a` files, as well.

Answer (score -1):

Its all good dont worry you built a static library MinGW gives .a files on windows too